# Interpretation of Curvature formula for a parametric curve

Tags: calculus

Given $S(t) = (x(t), y(t))$, the curvature at any point on S is given by below formula:

$$K = \dfrac{S'(t) \times S''(t)}{|S'(t)|^{3/2}}$$

Where $S'(t)$ is the first order derivative of $S(t)$
and $S''(t)$ is the second order derivative of $S(t).$

1. I know that the first order derivative gives the tangent vector function to the curve, but How do i interpret the second order derivative of a parametric curve?
2. In the above formula for curvature, how does more "perpendicular-ness" between $S'(t)$ and $S''(t)$ increases the curvature of the curve?

Comment: Aren't you missing the norm? In my book (wikipedia) it is: c(f) = | f' x f''| / |f'|^3. Note that | f' x f'' | measures the area of the parallelogram formed by f' and f'' which when f' and f'' are aligned is null, this makes sens since when velocity and acceleration are aligned their is no curvature.https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/curvature.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an intuitive explanation. The second derivative can be interpreted as acceleration. If you decompose acceleration in a tangential and orthogonal part with respect to the curve then the tangential part does not contribute to a change in direction (it only changes speed along the curve). So the curvature –how much you turn the steering wheel– depends only on the orthogonal part and your speed.

Comment: [+1] Good explanation... and this orthogonal part will be at its maximum when S' and S'' are orthogonal